# Optimizing a potion brewing program using ingredients and formulaic conversions in ruby?

Tags: ruby, computer-science

Here's the problem I'm solving:

> "The three witches in Hamlet can brew any potion provided they have the
>   right ingredients. Suppose that five ingredients are necessary in
>   making a health potion: eye of newt (eon), toe of frog (tof), wool of
>   bat (wob), adder’s fork (af), and tooth of wolf (tow). Four reactions
>   can >occur between these ingredients:
>
> 4 eon + 2 wob = 3 af + 4 tow
>   3 tow + 1 tof = 2 eon
>   1 wob + 2 af  = 1 tof
>   4 tof + 7 tow + 2 af = 1 health potion
>
> Assuming you can control the order of reactions, write a program that
>   can calculate the maximum number of health potions one can brew with a
>   given amount of ingredients. Here is example output: If I have 34 eon,
>   59 tof, 20 wob, 5 af, and 20 tow, I can make seven health potions.”
>
> Excerpt From: Ophir Frieder, Gideon Frieder, and David Grossman.
>   “Computer Science Programming Basics with Ruby.” iBooks.

And here's my solution:

```
ingredients = Hash.new
potion = 0

puts "Welcome to potion brewer! To make a health potion you must combine 4 TOF + 7 TOW + 2 AF. Let's get started.\n\n" 

puts "How many EON do you have?"

ingredients["EON"] = gets.to_i

puts "How many TOF do you have?" 

ingredients["TOF"] = gets.to_i

puts "How many WOB do you have?" 

ingredients["WOB"] = gets.to_i

puts "How many AF do you have?"

ingredients["AF"] = gets.to_i

puts "How many TOW do you have?" 

ingredients["TOW"] = gets.to_i


while (ingredients["EON"] >= 4 and ingredients["WOB"] >= 2)
    ingredients["AF"] += 3
    ingredients["TOW"] += 4
    ingredients["EON"] -= 4
    ingredients["WOB"] -= 2
    # ==/== DEBUG ==/== 
#    puts "4 EON and 2 WOB convereted into +3 AF and +4 TOW."
#    puts ingredients["EON"]
#    puts ingredients["WOB"]
end
while ((ingredients["TOF"]/4) < (ingredients["AF"]/2))
   ## puts "debug"
    if (ingredients["WOB"] >= 1 and ingredients["AF"] >= 2)
        ingredients["TOF"] += 1
        ingredients["WOB"] -= 1
        ingredients["AF"] -= 2
   #     puts "1 WOB and 2 AF converted to +1 TOF."
    else
    break
    end
end
while (ingredients["TOF"] >= 4 and ingredients["TOW"] >= 7 and ingredients["AF"] >= 2)
    potion += 1
    ingredients["TOF"] -= 4
    ingredients["TOW"] -= 7
    ingredients["AF"] -= 2
    # ==/== DEBUG ==/==
    #puts "Potion created.."
end


puts "\n\nMade #{potion} potion(s).\n\n" 

for name in ingredients.keys
puts "You have " + ingredients[name].to_s + " " + name + " left.\n"
end
```

Anyhow, this is the "tidiest" I could figure out how to solve the problem. I think I ordered the conversions correctly so that there won't be any inefficiencies in making the potions..and I got the desired result with the input from the example in the book.

Can anyone confirm that it actually seems ok/I didn't miss some major optimization that could further maximize my potions? I couldn't find much to do with the third conversion (1wob+2af=1tof).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem!

So let's rephrase it: the objective is to compute the "health" potion, and if any ingredient of this potion is missing , to find other potion that could be used to create the missing ingredient.

This sounds to be a recursive algorithm.
So first, let's modelise the "creating a potion" problem.

Suppose e have a potion formulae, a hash with all needed ingredient (with negative value) and the resulting ingreident, positive values.

For instance:

```
4 eon + 2 wob = 3 af + 4 tow
```

Could be written as:

```
formulae={:eon=>-4,:wob=>-2,:af=>3,:tow=>4}
```

So, computing a formulae would be as simple as:

```
def compute_formulae ingredients,formulae
   result=ingredients.clone
   formulae.each do |needed,amount|
     if ingredients[needed]<-amount
        puts "Missing #{needed}" # The is an ingredient missing, we should probably exit now
        return nil
     else
        result[needed]+=amount
     end
   end
   result
end
```

The problem now is what to do when there is a missing ingredient? We have to find a formulae that we can use to "create it", according to our existing ingredients, in the list of formulas

```
formulas=[
 {:tof=>-4,:tow=>-7,:af=>-2,:health=>1},
 {:eon=>-4,:wob=>-2,:af=>3,:tow=>4},
 {:tow=>-3,:tof=>-1,:eon=>2},
 {:wob=>-1,:af =>-2,:tof=>1}
  ]
formulas.each{|f| f.default=0} # Just ensure that there is de fault value for all ingredients


def find_missing_ingredient ingredients,formulas,missing
   formulas.each do | formulae |
      if formulae[missing]>0
        compute_formulae_ingredient ingredients,formulae
      end
   end
end

# so basically, the problem is
ingredients={:eon=>34,:tof=>59,:wob=>20,:af=>5,:tow=>20}
ingredients.default=0

while find_missing_ingredient ingredients,formulas,:health
end
```

Now, there are some small details, like the main loop (we need to continue as long as we can get new "health", errors (when to stop in this recursive loop), the input part ,  but I left this to the reader!

Comment: Thanks a ton! The book I'm using hasn't gone over a few of these methods, but I am definitely going to start looking them up to finish solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem intriguing!

Modelling the problem as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) can guarantee an optimal solution. Each node (vertex) in the graph represents a list of quantities of each ingredient remaining, while each edge represents an adjustment of the quantities of ingredients according to one of the reaction formulas.

To find the node with the most health potions, perform a [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) such as a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS) on the graph.

For each node, if there aren't enough ingredients to perform any reactions, return a count of health potions made. Otherwise, if the node is non-terminal, perform every valid reaction and return which one of these ultimately results in the most health potions.

A `memo` [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) can be used to avoid re-evaluating nodes, dramatically speeding up the algorithm.

Here's a relevant snippet which uses recursion as an implicit stack (to perform the DFS):

```
def max_potions(ingredients, memo={})

  # get all available reactions as a list
  reactions = get_reactions(ingredients)

  # if no reactions are possible, return 
  # the number of health potions made
  return ingredients[:hp] if reactions.empty?

  # try every possible reaction for this set 
  # of ingredients and determine the maxiumum
  maximum = 0

  reactions.each do |reaction|
    key = reaction.hash

    # retrieve this node's value if already visited
    if memo.include?(key)
      result = memo[key]
    else # calculate and save the node's value
      result = max_potions(reaction, memo)
      memo[key] = result
    end 

    # update the maximum as necessary
    maximum = result if result > maximum 
  end 

  return maximum
end
```

See [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/ggorlen/e0c1f56005e9bb11dbc8bb3035a39e09) for a working but bare-bones version.